# Java - Cant load relative files on OSX Sierra

Tags: java, macos, maven

I am maintaining a Java desktop Maven application that loads some properties from a relative file, the app was working fine on Mac, Linux and Windows.

However, after building the app with [GetDown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown) it cannot load the file anymore, but only when running on OSX Sierra!

the case is, it is working fine on all the OS's, but on mac Sierra it can't see the file if running with GetDown. but if i run the app on eclipse or using a jar file (with no getdown) it loads normally.

what i tried code wise ?

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file_path)
getClass().getResourceAsStream(file_path)
getClass().getResource(file_path)
```

example : if the file name was my_file,, i tried :

```
"./my_file"
"/my_file"
"my_file"
```

Nothing works, it is always NULL.

UPDATE :

this is how the jar looks like after being packed :
[image]

i am unable to load all the .properties files. 
however, i successfully loaded the contents of FXML folder. using the same way does not work for .properties files.

Comment: getResource() loads a file from the classpath, not necessarily from a filesystem path. It sounds like the file is not ending up the correct place when you build it wit Getdown. Can't say more about it, I can't look at your system to see what ends up where.

Comment: @Gimby i already considered that, but it is ending up at the exact same location !

Comment: I'd still take the cue to provide more information about the deployed structure, where files end up, etc. etc. It might just be a simple thing.

Comment: @Gimby check the update please